# How to avoid code duplication in List methods in Java?

Tags: java

The following method reads a file and returns a certain List type.

```
List<X> readFile(String file) {
    List<X> x = new ArrayList<X>();

    File f = new File(file);

    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readLines(f, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    List<X> xList = new ArrayList<X>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        xList.add(new X(line));
    }

    return xList;
}
```

Now a different list is required. The method has been copied and the following returns a different List type.

```
List<Y> readFile(String file) {
    List<Y> y = new ArrayList<Y>();

    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readLines(f, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    List<Y> yList = new ArrayList<Y>();
    for (String line : lines) {
        yList.add(new Y(line));
    }

    return yList;
}
```

The problem is that the class has been duplicated. How to avoid code duplication in such cases?

**Attempt**

```
avoidDuplicatedCode(){
    List<Y> y = new ArrayList<Y>();

    List<String> lines = null;
    try {
        lines = Files.readLines(f, Charsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return y
}
```

results in:

- set method return type to 'List'

when changed a lot of other issues occurs

Comment: What's the point in reading all the lines of a file if you don't do anything with them? What is the **actual** code of the methods? As is, you could replace the first one by `new ArrayList<X>()`, and the second one by `new ArrayList<Y>()`.

Comment: What's the point in reading a file, if you don't care about the `lines` list? And about your question: pass "something" which converts from `String` to `X` or `Y`, then you need only one generic method.

Comment: I forgot to add a missing part of the code, i.e. the part that adds the lines to a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can introduce generic parameter:

```
<T> List<T> readFile(String file) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    // ...
    return list;
}

public void foo() {
    List<Integer> l1 = readFile("l1");
    List<String> l2 = readFile("l2");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining. Another issue I have is that a new Object is created within the class. Could this be made generic as well (`xList.add(new X(line));` vs. `yList.add(new Y(line));`)?

Comment: @Alfred, you can't do it easily because of erasure, generic types are not available at runtime. But there are some workarounds, for example, you can pass a function that creates T as additional argument